# leaflet-radar + react : checkbox_div is not defined error

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

*Note: Using React*

I'm having trouble setting up a radar in my leaflet map object. I'm able to generate the map easily, but I get an error when I try adding a radar to the map.

[image: Google Chrome error message]

The issue comes from this slice of code:

```
import RadarMap from 'leaflet-radar'
.
.
.
drawMap(){
    let radar;

    this.map = L.map(this.id);// eslint-disable-line
    this.map.setView([this.latitude, this.longitude], this.zoom);

    L.tileLayer("https://tile-{s}.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", { // eslint-disable-line
        accessToken: this.accessToken
      }
    ).addTo(this.map);

    radar = new L.Control.Radar({}); // eslint-disable-line
    radar.addTo(this.map);
  }
```

The error specifically occurs when I call this line:

```
radar.addTo(this.map);
```

If I don't call this line, my code will correctly generate a map. But this one line
breaks the map.

To be frank, I've been working on this error for hours now. I've altered this code zealously;
yet iteration after iteration, I still can't get this radar to work. If anyone knows how to help me with this problem, I'd be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

Leaflet-radar was trying to use a global variable named **checkbox_div**. Since **checkbox_div** did not exist as a global variable, an error was raised. Adding **checkbox_div** as a global variable fixed the error.

I solved this error by using globalThis in the constructor of the element and using that to add a global variable.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    globalThis.checkbox_div = undefined; // eslint-disable-line
  }
```

In my solution, I gave **checkbox_div** the value of undefined, but I think it's possible to give **checkbox_div** any value. Just instantiating **checkbox_div** is the key.

An alternative solution would be to simply add **checkbox_div** in the .html file like this

```
<script>
  var checkbox_div;
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).